# PHPStorm / IntelliJ IDEA Live Template string "$" concatenation

Tags: laravel, intellij-idea, live-templates

Does anyone know how to prefix a "$" next to a $STRING$ entry? $$STRING$ seems to remove the ability for the template system to recognise this as an input variable.

While we are on the topic, is it possible to concatenate/edit a previously declared variable in the variable editor? So setting:

$STRING$'s default to: $VAR$ . "suffix"

Both of these would be very useful!!

Cheers

Comment: i don't understand your problem. ://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Just use `$$` (therefore `$$$STRING$`).

---

To clarify the OP's problem with an example:

Imagine that you wanted to have an `n` live template (macro) that creates a new instance of a class and stores it in a variable of the same name (Netbeans users will know :) ).

So if you used the `n` macro and typed `Person`, the output would be `$person = new Person();`

And since you want to autocomplete the `$person` variable based on `Person` class, you need to have `$<variable> = new <Class>();`, which translates to `$$$VAR$ = new $CLASS$(); $END$` in PhpStorm.

---

For anyone interested in the full `n` live template:

[image: The full template in PhpStorm]

---

My answer is indirectly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38883122/5500468).